# Why does this script work from the command line, but not when I put it in a windows batch file?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

This is the script I can run from the commandline:

`(for /r %i in (*) do @echo %~fsi) | clip`

But inside a batch file, I get a syntax error about unexpected brackets....

```
) was unexpected at this time.

(for /r ~fsi) | clip
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in batch:

```
@Echo Off
(for /r %%i in (*) do echo %%~fsi) | clip
```

You must double-up % signs on running in batch files.

Comment: **"You must double-up % signs on running in batch files."**. The key point.

Comment: Use FOR /? to get a helpful short manual, it explains this %% usage and a whole number of other useful tricks FOR can do.